# What is the Distribution Function for the Difference of Independent Gumbel Type 1 RVs?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ follow iid Type 1 Extreme Value distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (the shape parameter $\xi = 0$).

How can we find the following probability

$$\mathbb{P}(X - Y < B),$$

where $B$ is some constant?

Comment: A good starting point is to provide the functional form of the pdf you are working with. Specifying the mean and variance of Gumbel Type 1 is not a standard way to define the distribution. Perhaps you intend something quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X,Y \sim Gumbel(\mu,\beta)$ where the PDF of a Gumbell$(\mu,\beta)$ distribution is $\frac{1}{\beta} e^{-(z+e^{-z})}$ where $z= \frac{x-\mu}{\beta}$, then the characteristic function for $X$ is $\phi(t) = \Gamma(1-i \beta t) e^{i \mu t}$.

Thus, the characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $E[e^{t (X-Y)}] = E[e^{tX}] E[e^{-t Y}] = \phi(t) \phi(-t) = \Gamma(1-i \beta t) e^{i \mu t}\Gamma(1+i \beta t) e^{-i \mu t} = \Gamma(1-i \beta t) \Gamma(1+i \beta t) = \frac{\pi \beta t}{\sinh (\pi \beta t)} $

We can then match this to the characteristic function of a Logistic$(0,\beta)$ R.V. , which has CDF $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x/\beta}}$. Taking $x=B$ gives $P(X-Y \leq B) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-B/\beta}}$.

Note that in this choice of parameters for the Gumbel distribution, the mean is $\mu + \beta \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant, and the variance is $\frac{\pi^2}{6} \beta^2$. It is straightforward to adjust to this parameter set.

Comment: The author specifies that $\mu$ denotes the mean, whereas the mean of your specified distribution is plainly not $\mu$. I think the OP should correct or clarify the question.

Comment: I've added a line to note what the mean and variance of this distribution are. It's a straightforward exercise to translate the parameters OP uses to the parameters I took off wikipedia.